# Change <img> source after window.location.replace

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-applications

When I press a button on my main page, it retrieves a link to an image using an api. Then I want to redirect to another page of mine and change the src attribute to the link i fetched with the api (on the new page).

Everything works besides the change image source.

Main page button:

```
<button onclick="search()" class="submit-button">SEARCH</button>
```

Java Script (Edit: JavaScript is stored in separate file 'script.js')

```
function search() {
    const username = document.getElementById("username").value

    // API CALL HERE WHICH CALLS presentImg()

}

function presentImage(url) {
    console.log(url)
    window.location.replace("profile.html")

    document.getElementById("image").src = url;

}
```

Profile.html

```
<img id="image" src="#">
```

When I open the main page and click the button I am redirected and the profile.html page opens but the image is not displayed. I have already checked the url, it works and shows only one image. I also tried to load a local image in my project folder, that doesn't work either.

Comment: After you are changing or replacing  the page to profile.html. Make sure you change the image src now in that profile.html file. Because old page is now useless and will not consider any javaScript for it.

Comment: You're redirecting to the page before you update your image...

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what i want. Don't i target the new (profile.html) site with  `document.getElementById("image").src`? The JavaScript is stored in a separate file. @Shamoon97

Comment: @JoeyM But i want to update it on the new page

Comment: @pama link your JS file in `profile.html` then call your function that replaces the image?